# How to replace just numbers in string using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have String like this

```
"{"name:John","Age:15","width:500","height:300"},{"name:Mike","Age:25","width:600","height:400"}";
```

how i can replace the numbers just after width and height to be like this

```
"{"name:John","Age:15","width:100","height:100"},{"name:Mike","Age:25","width:100","height:100"}";
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this a part of a json string?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific questions about problems you've run into writing your code. Take a stab at it, read the documentation, tutorials, etc., and then ask if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search using this regex:

```
(width|height):\d+
```

and replace with:

```
$1:100
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vB5vV8/1)

**Java:**

```
str = str.replaceAll("(width|height):\\d+", "$1:100");
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Most of the Indians in SO will do grammatical mistakes (including me). I don't know whether this sentence contains any grammatical mistakes or not.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply :)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, we can use a list of alternatives in a look-behind ([see *Java takes things a step further by allowing finite repetition*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)), and their length does not have to be identical:

```
String str = "\"{\"name:John\",\"Age:15\",\"width:500\",\"height:300\"},{\"name:Mike\",\"Age:25\",\"width:600\",\"height:400\"}\";";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=width:|height:)\\d+", "100"));
```

Output of a [demo program](https://ideone.com/qGDnI6):

```
"{"name:John","Age:15","width:100","height:100"},{"name:Mike","Age:25","width:100","height:100"}";
```